# javafx8: Different behaviours of TreeView on AnchorPane and other panes(StackPane, VBox etc)

Tags: java, treeview, javafx-8

I'm trying to create TreeView with editable items, but I faced with different behaviour of TreeView depending on what Pane is used.

For example, if I add my TreeView to StackPane or VBox, I get proper behavior of the each TreeItem in my TreeView. Code below demonstrates that TreeItem in the TreeView has context menu & can be edited succesfully.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.TextFieldTreeCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.converter.DefaultStringConverter;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TreeView view = new TreeView(new TreeItem("root item"));
        view.setEditable(true);
        ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu(new MenuItem("A"), new MenuItem("B"), new MenuItem("C"));
        view.setCellFactory(v -> {
            return new TextFieldTreeCell<String>(new DefaultStringConverter()) {  
            @Override
            public void updateItem(String value, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(value, empty);

                if (empty || value == null) {
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    setText(getItem() == null ? "" : getItem());
                    setGraphic(getTreeItem().getGraphic());
                    setContextMenu(menu);
                    setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
                }
            }
        };});

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(view);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }  
}
```

But if I change this line `StackPane root = new StackPane();` with `AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();`, a new empty TreeItem will be added to my TreeView while editing each time when a new String value will be commited to the existing TreeItem. In addition these new TreeItems also will have context menu. 
How I can get regular behaviour of TreeView on the AnchorPane?
Thanks

Comment: There are very few valid uses for an AnchorPane.  Why do you need to use one?  What’s wrong with a StackPane or BorderPane?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the behavior you describe.  I copied and pasted the code, changed the `StackPane` to an `AnchorPane`, and (apart from a slight, and expected, difference in layout) the behavior was identical.

Comment: You should, though, set the context menu to null if the cell is empty, as well as setting the text and graphic to null.